# filter functions keeps failing with missing data argument

Tags: r, function, nls

I am working on Marketing Mix Modeling and I am following the article

https://analyticsartist.wordpress.com/2014/01/31/adstock-rate-deriving-with-analytical-methods/

The article defines the adstock function as below :

```
adstock <- function(x, rate=0){
  return(as.numeric(filter(x=x, filter=rate, method="recursive")))
}
```

and further uses `nlsm` from `minpack.lm` package in R which calculates the rates and the coefficients.

```
model1 <- nlsLM(Applications~b0 + b1 * adstock(Media1, r1) + b2 * adstock(Media2, r2) +
                  b3 * adstock(Media3, r3) + b4 * adstock(Media4, r4) + b5 * adstock(Media5, r5) +
                  b6 * adstock(Media6, r6) + b7 * adstock(Media7, r7),
                algorithm = "LM",
                start     = c(b0=   1, b1=   1, b2=   1, b3 = 1, b4 = 1, b5 =1, b6= 1, b7= 1, r1=0, r2=0, r3=0, r4=0, r5=0, r6=0, r7=0),
                lower     = c(b0=-Inf, b1=-Inf, b2=-Inf, b3 = -Inf, b4 = -Inf, b5 =-Inf, b6= -Inf, b7= -Inf, r1=0, r2=0, r3=0, r4=0, r5=0, r6=0,     r7=0),
                upper     = c(b0= Inf, b1= Inf, b2= Inf, b3 = Inf, b4 = Inf, b5 =Inf, b6= Inf, b7= Inf, r1=0.5, r2=0.5, r3=0.5, r4=0.5, r5=0.5, r6=0.5, r7=0.5))
```

However, the model keeps failing with the below error

```
Error in filter_(.data, .dots = compat_as_lazy_dots(...)) : 
argument ".data" is missing, with no default
```

It seems that the error is coming the from the adstock function but I am not sure how to fix it.

I am really hoping if someone could please help to get this resolved.

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: Which `filter` function do you *think* you're using? That error looks like `dplyr::filter`, but the arguments you're listing there look like something else.

Comment: Try using `return(as.numeric(stats::filter(...)))` (using your actual args).

Comment: @r2evans, I guess this is the biggest blunder I would have made in my life. You are correct it was getting masked from the `dplyr::filter` and `stats::filter` resolved the issue. Sincere apologies if I have wasted your time in any way and thanks a lot for the response.

Comment: (What's odd is I've seen this type of question before where `dplyr::filter` masks `stats::filter`, but I can't find a representative question easily.)

Comment: True, I was looking for the same but it did not find any questions

Comment: *"biggest blunder"* ... one complaint I have (heresy?) with R is the masking of functions. I often prefer more deliberate namespace management, such as python's `import pandas as pd` vice R's analogous `import * from pandas`. Regardless of my preference, however, many of my own bugs have been due to masking. There is (typically?) a warning when the masking happens on package load, but it's easy to forget or miss. Glad this resolved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is a common question, but since I cannot find the duplicate, I'll provide an answer for now.)

The error you're seeing here is from `dplyr::filter`, not what you expect to be using: `stats::filter`. You should have seen something like the following at some point when you loaded `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
# Attaching package: 'dplyr'
# The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#     filter, lag
# The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
```

They way around this (and encouraged/forced when publishing packages to CRAN) is to be explicit when using non-base functions. I would generally have thought that `stats::` would be immune from this, but the use of `dplyr` certainly mandates it.

So the fix for your code is to simply be explicit when using `filter` anywhere near `dplyr`:

```r
adstock <- function(x, rate=0){
  return(as.numeric(stats::filter(x=x, filter=rate, method="recursive")))
}
```

FWIW, R's namespace management and rough equivalency with python's more explicit methods:

```
R                          Python
----------------------     ----------------------
                           import pkgname         | explicit namespace use
pkgname::function(...)     pkgname.function(...)  |

                           import pkgname as p    | no R equivalent?
                           p.function(...)        |

library(pkgname)           import * from pkgname  | permissive namespace,
function(...)              function(...)          |   enables masking
```

Comment: Thanks for the long explanation r2evans. This is the strange thing when I load my library `library(dplyr)`. i do not get the mask warning.

Comment: Even with a fresh instance of R? It doesn't show the warning on reloads, but it should on the first one. Odd.